# login page and navigation bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface, interface-builder

When first launching the apps, I want it to show a button to log in. After successfully logged in, I want the app to show a tab bar view.. So does this mean that I need to set my app delegate to point to the UITabBarController? How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I load my UITabBarController in the app delegate, so before adding the login screen the last bit of the applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions looks like this:

```
[window addSubview:tabcontroller.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

To add a view that covers the tabbar you simply insert it after the tabbarcontroller and before the makeKeyAndVisible, like this:

```
[window addSubview:tabcontroller.view];
[window addSubview:loginViewController.view];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

The "loginViewController" view will appear covering everything. Once you dismiss it the tab bar will be visible and usable.

Comment: so the code that would be dismissing this login view is in the loginViewController class right? My guess would be just to use [self.view removeFromSuperview] after we're done?

Comment: Right. I use the animated removal:    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];